# How to update Json object with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, php, json, magento, prototypejs

I am trying to figure out a way to change the values in a JSON object with a dynamic name.

For example my modified object within the template looks now looks like so:

```
var optionsPrice_<?php echo $_product->getId() ?> = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

I have to make this variable unique as there are multiple products on the page and we need to target each one individually.

This object is then modified within a function using:

```
optionsPrice.changePrice('config', {'price': price, 'oldPrice': oldPrice});
```

How can I access the dynamic object and then modify it? I don't want to change to much of the JS to get this to work.

I have thought about keeping the name as 'optionsPrice' and then cycle through all the objects and modify the correct one based on the ID they contain. This doesn't seem very efficient though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may use an object instead of a single variable:

```
var optionsPrice = {}
optionsPrice[<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>] = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Then you can reference it as:

```
console.log(optionsPrice[YOUR_ID_HERE]);
console.log(optionsPrice["20"]); // Example
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However the problem I have now is because the object structure has changed the keys now contain undefined values. I might need to modify how these values are now assigned to cater for the new structure unless there is another way to do it.